# Как объединить две части одного DataFrame по одинаковым значениям в двух столбцах?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть списки с регионами (странами) и показатель к ним (цифры). Таким "комплектов" может быть достаточно много, но мне нужно разобраться с двумя. Списки стран разные. В общем нужно по двум столбцам пройтись и оставить только повторяющиеся значения, которые были в обоих столбцах. В новый столбец вывести это список и рядом соответствующие значения показателей...

Таблица имеет примерно такой формат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В текстовом виде:

```
In [155]: df
Out[155]:
                   Region1    x1                 Region2         x2
0              Afghanistan  11.0             Afghanistan  41.750000
1                  Albania  36.0                  Angola  35.300000
2                  Algeria  36.0                 Albania  23.000000
3                   Angola  15.0              Arab World  23.700000
4                Argentina  32.0               Argentina   8.933333
5                  Armenia  35.0                 Armenia  11.300000
6                Australia  79.0     Antigua and Barbuda   6.900000
7                  Austria  76.0              Azerbaijan  33.950000
8               Azerbaijan  29.0                 Burundi  27.800000
9                  Bahrain  51.0                   Benin  24.500000
10              Bangladesh  25.0            Burkina Faso  16.250000
11                 Belarus  32.0              Bangladesh  54.000000
12                 Belgium  77.0                Bulgaria   8.833333
13                   Benin  37.0            Bahamas, The  21.000000
14                  Bhutan  65.0  Bosnia and Herzegovina  10.450000
15                 Bolivia  34.0                 Belarus  12.200000
16  Bosnia and Herzegovina  38.0                  Belize   6.200000
17                Botswana  63.0                 Bolivia  13.566667
18                  Brazil  38.0                  Brazil  11.700000
19                Bulgaria  41.0                Barbados   1.200000
20            Burkina Faso  38.0                  Bhutan   3.600000
```

**На выходе хочу получить нечто такое**

```
                Region       x1      x2
0              Afghanistan  11.0   41.75            
1                  Albania  36.0   23.00               
2                Argentina  32.0   8.93
```

PS не знаю только ли в pandas это делается или может подключить numpy?

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример дата сета, который вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно объединить две части DataFrame как два отдельных DataFrame по индексу, воспользовавшись методом [DataFrame.set_index(column_name)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). Предварительно надо преобразовать столбцы `Region1` и `Region2` в индексы:

```
In [174]: res = (df.set_index('Region1')[['x1']]
     ...:          .join(df.set_index('Region2')[['x2']], how='inner')
     ...:          .reset_index())
     ...:

In [175]: res
Out[175]:
                     index    x1         x2
0              Afghanistan  11.0  41.750000
1                  Albania  36.0  23.000000
2                   Angola  15.0  35.300000
3                Argentina  32.0   8.933333
4                  Armenia  35.0  11.300000
5               Azerbaijan  29.0  33.950000
6               Bangladesh  25.0  54.000000
7                  Belarus  32.0  12.200000
8                    Benin  37.0  24.500000
9                   Bhutan  65.0   3.600000
10                 Bolivia  34.0  13.566667
11  Bosnia and Herzegovina  38.0  10.450000
12                  Brazil  38.0  11.700000
13                Bulgaria  41.0   8.833333
14            Burkina Faso  38.0  16.250000
```

---

**UPDATE:** чтобы сгруппировать DataFrame по схожим столбцам можно воспользоваться группировкой по столбцам и методом [pd.concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\qq.xlsx')

res = pd.concat([x.dropna().set_index(x.columns[0])
                 for g,x in df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1], axis='columns')],
                axis='columns', sort=True)
```

результат:

```
In [262]: res
Out[262]:
                         x1         x2   x3        x4            x5
Afghanistan            11.0  41.750000  NaN  0.995955    569.577923
Albania                36.0  23.000000  3.9  2.171774   3952.830781
Algeria                36.0  18.800000  4.0  1.631480   4160.220067
American Samoa          NaN        NaN  NaN  3.845253  11865.963232
Andorra                 NaN        NaN  NaN  4.076003  36038.267604
Angola                 15.0  35.300000  NaN  1.418066   3683.552607
Anguilla                NaN        NaN  NaN  2.460751           NaN
Antigua and Barbuda     NaN   6.900000  NaN  3.089894  13659.147914
Arab World              NaN  23.700000  NaN       NaN   6413.377161
Argentina              32.0   8.933333  3.8  1.729188  13698.293438
...                     ...        ...  ...       ...           ...
Venezuela, RB           NaN   7.050000  NaN  0.467624           NaN
Viet Nam                NaN        NaN  4.3       NaN           NaN
Vietnam                31.0  32.200000  NaN  2.160656   2065.169099
Virgin Islands (U.S.)   NaN        NaN  NaN  3.383753  34954.971683
West Bank and Gaza      NaN   5.600000  NaN  1.994149   2865.805109
World                   NaN  18.067480  NaN       NaN  10172.222817
Yemen                  18.0        NaN  NaN       NaN           NaN
Yemen, Rep.             NaN  66.600000  NaN  1.228918   1285.563019
Zambia                 38.0  11.450000  3.9  2.270275   1313.889646
Zimbabwe               21.0  16.850000  3.5  1.183372   1033.415841

[280 rows x 5 columns]
```

чтобы удалить все строки где присутствует хотя бы один `NaN`:

```
res = res.dropna()
```

результат:

```
In [266]: res
Out[266]:
                          x1         x2   x3        x4            x5
Albania                 36.0  23.000000  3.9  2.171774   3952.830781
Algeria                 36.0  18.800000  4.0  1.631480   4160.220067
Argentina               32.0   8.933333  3.8  1.729188  13698.293438
Armenia                 35.0  11.300000  4.0  2.112149   3617.935746
Azerbaijan              29.0  33.950000  4.5  1.826306   5500.310382
Bangladesh              25.0  54.000000  3.8  1.748720   1210.158769
Benin                   37.0  24.500000  3.5  1.964261    783.963078
Bhutan                  65.0   3.600000  3.8  3.022356   2615.310220
Bolivia                 34.0  13.566667  3.6  1.358934   3077.026199
Bosnia and Herzegovina  38.0  10.450000  3.7  2.218637   4584.242548
...                      ...        ...  ...       ...           ...
Tanzania                30.0  21.250000  3.6  2.128381    872.295495
Thailand                38.0   9.900000  4.6  2.352295   5846.394608
Trinidad and Tobago     39.0  10.500000  3.9  2.384004  17941.800592
Tunisia                 38.0  10.300000  3.9  2.438445   3828.100633
Turkey                  42.0   7.300000  4.4  2.386981  10984.805202
Uganda                  25.0  20.300000  3.7  2.114222    675.121142
Ukraine                 27.0  44.450000  4.0  1.686449   2124.662666
Uruguay                 74.0   2.266667  4.1  3.212427  15524.842468
Zambia                  38.0  11.450000  3.9  2.270275   1313.889646
Zimbabwe                21.0  16.850000  3.5  1.183372   1033.415841

[91 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, мой друг! Однако когда я пытаюсь проанализировать большее количество данных, питон выдает мне
27 Ethiopia 33.0 13.366667 3.7
28 Gabon 34.0 23.200000 3.8
29 Georgia 52.0 6.000000 4.2
... ... ... ... ...
496141 NaN NaN NaN NaN
496142 NaN NaN NaN NaN
496143 NaN NaN NaN NaN
т.е. программа проходится видимо по всем возможным строкам эксель

Comment: @Max, можете выложить ваш Excel файл на какой-нибудь свободный файлообменник?

Comment: Держите, https://dropmefiles.com/yDORZ

Comment: @Max, добавил более универсальный вариант...

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, но как теперь удалить те строки где присутствует NaN?

Comment: @Max, `res = res.dropna()` ?